# SerDes LVDS termination with isolation

Tags: fpga, isolation, termination

I have the following chain:
[image]

There are two FPGAs (Microsemi and Lattice) that I am connecting through LVDS SerDes communication. The two FPGAs have isolated power thus the isolation for the data in between.

My question, is this the correct way to do termination with data isolation in the chain? only on the Rx side from both end should be impedance matched?

I am also debating if it is better to use the on chip termination of the FPGA or not.. currently the isolation is external (off chip) and ODT are turned off. I understand that it boils to power consumption for the on or off chip termination, is this correct?

The signals are true differential and for now both sides are DC coupled. I might need to AC couple FPGA 2 (lattice) because of CM voltage. Microsemi uses LVDS33 while Lattice uses G8B10B IO standards.

Comment: Do the two FPGAs have a common ground?

Comment: No, they are isolated

Comment: According to the data sheet, the ADN4655 has termination resistors on the diff signals.  If that's the case, you don't need the separate 100 ohm resistors you've shown.

Comment: I think it was noted in the datasheet to place the resistors externally so there are no internal termination